# django validationerror not being raised

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I have created a a dynamic formset that allows the user to add or remove as many forms as they want. Now, I am trying to do custom validation in a field(block_name) in the forms.

It seems like it is working because if the user input doesn't match a certain regex, then the data will not be saved. The problem is that there is no message showing that the input is wrong.

Also, if the user inputs incorrect data and tries to submit the page will redirect to itself and erase all the input data. How can I make the page stay in the same view if the input is wrong and also show error messages?

forms.py:

```
import re
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from inventory.models import Block
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


# Form for block requests
class BlockForm(forms.ModelForm):
block_name = forms.CharField(required=True, validators= [RegexValidator('^s\d{3}rf\d*b\d*e\d+r\d+w\d*[cgls][abcdex][ed][hv][sbaec][a-d] [a-d][0-7][apfg]a', message="Please enter valid block name",  code="invalid_name")])

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BlockForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.empty_permitted = False

class Meta:
    model = Block
    fields = ['block_name', 'block_derivatives', 'block_subsystems', 'owners']

def clean_block_name(self):
    print self.cleaned_data
    block_name = self.cleaned_data.get('block_name')
    if block_name == "a":
        print ("block name is a")
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            ('Please enter a block name'))            

    return block_name
```

models.py:

```
import datetime
import re
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from django.db import models 
from django.utils import timezone

class Inventory(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Inventories"

inventory_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return self.inventory_name

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Block(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Request Blocks"

inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, null=True)
block_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
#617block_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, validators=[block_nameTest])
block_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
block_derivatives = models.CharField(max_length=100)
block_subsystems = models.CharField(max_length=40)
owners = models.CharField(max_length=100)


def __str__(self):              
    return self.block_name

def block_owners(self):
    return str(self.owners)
```

views.py:

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response



from .models import Inventory, Block
from .forms import BlockForm
# Create your views here.


def requests(request, inventory_id):
    BlockFormSet = formset_factory(BlockForm, extra=1)
    inventory = get_object_or_404(Inventory, pk=inventory_id)
    formset = BlockFormSet(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = BlockFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:               
            print form
            form.save()
            print "Success"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/inventory/2')
        else:
            print "Yo, this stuff is not validated"

    else:      
        print "LOLOLOLOL"

    return render(request, 'inventory/requests.html', {'inventory': inventory, 'formset': BlockFormSet})
```

requests.html:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="requestForm">
<form id="blockForm" class="original" action="{% url 'inventory:requests' inventory.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}   
<!-- <a href="#" id="insert-more"> Add New Row </a> -->



        {{formset.management_form}}

        {% for form in formset %}

        <div class='item'>
            <ul>{{ form.as_table}}<ul>
            <p style=""><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <p><a id="add" href="#">Add another item</a></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Blocks" id="submitButton">




</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting after an invalid POST, rather than redisplaying the same form. Even though your redirect is to the same view, it loses the POST data and the form is therefore blank.

Drop the first `else` block, and let execution fall through to the final `render` line.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I just got rid of the redirect after an invalid POST, but it still wipes my data. You can check my edited code above.